# Is there a way to upload information to server using Tor and regular google search will find it?

Tags: security, censorship, ip-address

Is there a way to upload information to server so there won't be a way to detect its real IP such as by using TOR. In addition, the content of it will be shown in regular browser google search? Is there a way to make sure that search engines will always show it even if the search engines decided to take off the index?

Comment: No. If a search engine decides to remove the listing, it's not listed.

Comment: @Avi Your question is a little confusing. Are you speaking as a website or web service admin or as any regular users without such privileges? Or both?

Comment: Thanks, both:  website or web service admin and as any regular users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple: use a Tor hidden service for a separate instance of your website admin panel and log no IP inside it, like in a plugin "This post was made from IP address 1.2.3.4"... After that there's a usuall posting - via Tor - no traces found. If your website is open to Internet/Clearnet - it will be indexed just as a usual website.

The Tor itself here is just a transport layer *for posting*, it's not altering a website behaviour.

And, yes, if you're banned from a search engine - Tor won't help you either: Website-to-SearchEngine interaction is done completely in clearnet, as usual, no Tor involved.